# Magento 2.3.3 - Unable connect error - Nginx - Centos 7 - PHP 7.1

Tags: php, configuration, nginx, magento2.3.3, centos

After successfully install magento 2.3.3 in centos 7 with nginx, url getting Unable connect error.

[Install nginx](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html#centos-7)

[Configure nginx](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html#configure-nginx-centos)

Install magento 2.3 using following commands,

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento2
>   --db-host=localhost --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="abc" --admin-lastname="abc" --admin-email=abc@gmail.com --admin-user="magento2" --admin-password="magento2123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="Asia/Kolkata" --use-rewrites="1"

[Configure SELinux and Firewalld](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html#configure-selinux-and-firewalld)

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf**

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
  listen 8091;
  server_name 192.168.1.64;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2;
  include /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

If i try the url : **19.168.1.64:8091** getting error like  **Unable connect error**

Anything else i missed?

Comment: 502 is cause due to a php issue, check your php version compatibility and also cross check required php extensions for magento 2.3.3

Comment: @ASQ Check with my updated post my php version : 7.1.33

Answer (score 0):

correct way installing to localhost is:

1. add your domain to hosts file: `192.168.1.64 myshop.com`
2. change magento base url as:

   `php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://myshop.com/"
    php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://myshop.com/"
    php bin/magento cache:flush`
3. add domain name to nginx config: `listen 8091; server_name myshop.com;`

open your browser with: `http://myshop.com/`

this is it.

Comment: I just testing with local host, intstead of "http://myshop.com/" shall i use "http://localhost/magento2"?

Comment: @ vim /etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf  https://justpaste.it/3me3h

Comment: domain name and base url must be the same, you can use your base url as: `http://192.168.1.64:8091/`  but better option to avoid using `localhost` in base url and even subfolder.